# innerHeight неправильно высчитывает высоту блока

Tags: css, jquery, gulp, browsersync

Использую JQuery
Хочу зафиксировать фильтр, когда доскролю до конца блока.
При первой перезагрузке бывает показывает верную высоту, но при второй уже неверную.

В чем может быть проблема?

сам код

```
let sidebar = $("#sidebar");// сам блок
let filter = $("#filter"); // фильтр внутри блока
let sidebarH = sidebar.innerHeight();

$(document).on('scroll', function() {

    let scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if( scrollTop >= sidebarH) {
        $(".filter").css('position', 'absolute');
    } else {
        $(".filter").css('position', 'fixed');
    }
    console.log(sidebarH);
});
```

Если открыть страницу в браузере, то код работает верно. Но если работать на локальном сервере (browsersync) в Gulp, то код не работает как должен

Comment: Посмотрите что в `sidebarH` во время выполнения. Возможно код отрабатывает до того, как блок sidebar примет правильный размер. Добавьте подробностей. Вы выводите в консоль высоту, что там? Неверная высота эта какая?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин Высота блока равна 2485px. 
В console.log показывает высоту 820px. Но при первой перезагрузке после редактирования документа показывает 2485px

Comment: Очень похоже на то, что sidebar не успевает принять нужную высоту. Что если переместить вычисление sidebarH внутрь обработчика on('scroll')? (временное решение для локализации проблемы)

Comment: @ЕгорБанин так работает верно

Comment: Ну значит ищите когда у вас выставляется высота блока и когда выполняется ваш код. Нужно гарантировать, что код выполнится после установки высоты. Сейчас это происходит асинхронно (наперегонки), а надо чтобы определение высоты было строго после её установки.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю как закрыть вопрос. мне помог @ЕгорБанин
sidebar не успевал принять нужную высоту. Помогло перемещение вычисления sidebarH внутрь обработчика on('scroll')